# Is there somewhere where I can ask general programming or best practice questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Sometimes it would be really helpful to ask other users how they would deal with a certain problem, or what best practice would be with regards to solving a problem. This does not involve specific code discussion.

Where can I post such questions? From reading the rules StackOverflow doesnt seem appropriate?

If there isn't such a place, maybe one should be created?

Andy

Comment: There isn't anywhere here. A site called non-programming was created long ago, it failed because nobody wanted to answer any of the questions there.

Comment: @RobertLongson *Technically*, it still exists, but questions about this topic are no longer accepted there; go look up its Area 51 proposal.

Comment: @RobertLongson thats a real shame, because such Q&A would add greatly to the value this site gives the wider programming community

Comment: @Andy Well, there's Reddit and Quora :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please no XD

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on

Comment: @Andy To some extend you can ask that kind of question at SE Software Engineering. But even there you'll need to be quite specific and not just asking for opinions.

Comment: @Andy The reason you don't want to ask on Reddit or Quora are the exact reasons people here don't want to answer those questions.

Comment: @fbueckert fair enough. I also read the links that Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog shared and it makes sense why such a general place doesn't exist. Just for an honest newb like me would be helpful occasionally

Comment: Sure.  Not arguing it wouldn't be useful.  For a while.  Allowing it would kill the site, and now you can't get *any* help here anymore.  These types of suggestions come up pretty often, with people arguing that it should be allowed because this is where the expertise is.  None of them realize that doing so will drive away the very reason they want to ask those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the exact question.

If it's completely opinion-based (e.g. "should curly braces be kept on the same line or a different line") and every answer is equally valid, there is no Stack Exchange site where it's on-topic.

If it's based on factual evidence of why one practice, convention, etc, is better than another, it may be on-topic for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). Please be sure to read their [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages before posting and make sure it fits the scope.